# Limited number of rows in QLDB

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb, partiql

I need limited number of rows while fetch the data from **QLDB**. Unfortunately, QLDB does not support **Limit** function in it's queries. However, **MySQL** supports the feature of limited number of rows from table.

But, I have seen the **Reserve Words** in QLDB. Here is the link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.reserved.html
In this documentation, these Reserved words could be use in quoted identifier with double quotation marks (for example, "user").

My query is: `SELECT * FROM Balance "LIMIT" 3`
still it's not working. Kindly give some suggestions to get limited number of rows from QLDB Tables for pagination purpose.

Answer (score 1):

QLDB does not currently (2021/09/09) support LIMIT queries. It is a reserved word in PartiQL which is an independent SQL language implemented by QLDB. Support for LIMIT will eventually be added to QLDB but there is no timeline for that as yet.

Pagination would have to be implemented in your client code today.